# How to copy in PostgreSQL from an CSV file and ignore quotations?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import a CSV file which has a delimiter but also quotations in the data such as " and '.

The command is:

```
COPY products FROM '/home/products.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV;
```

The data is has some products that have " in them (for instance: 40" TV) - for which I get the error:

> ERROR: unterminated CSV quoted field

Does somebody know how I can tell PostgreSQL to take the data with the quotes?

Comment: Are your strings quoted? Can you edit your question and show the example of the data in the CSV?

Comment: It looks like your file violates csv rule#5 from [rfc4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180): _If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then  double quotes may not appear inside the fields_. You won't be able to import it directly, the file should be pre-processed to fix that.

Comment: @Ainar-G: For instance a line could be:
`40"TV, 299.99, Televisions`

Comment: @NilsTierecke This is not your data, show us the example of what's in the file. Also, take a look at Daniel's comment. If your strings are not quoted, you have a malformed CSV and you need to fix the file.

Comment: @Ainar-G: `31822|M|2929038|312592 - 10|312592|1687885|133411836|5|20141127|4908|40" Chest Reg` is the line that fails. And yes, the strings are not quoted but I can't influence it.

Comment: @NilsTierecke This looks like a broken file to me. You have to either regenerate it with quotes, or create a corrected version using instruments like `sed`.

Comment: @Ainar-G Thanks a lot! - I'll try some `sed` and piping magics